# Android Studio emulator parameters

Tags: android-studio

Android studio launches emulator with such command line:

> /Users/sergey/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_22_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none

How do I add additional options? I need to specify *-http-proxy* command line parameter

Answer (score 2):

First, run the emulator from the terminal:

> /Users/sergey/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_22_x86 -"all parameters you need"

Then, clic on the run button in Android Studio. Select your device, that is already running. Your app will deploy there.

Answer (score 1):

The command to run start Nexus_5X_Edited_API_23 emulator with proxy setting (get more params [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html))

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_Edited_API_23 -http-proxy http://username:password@local_server:8080
```

also You can list all emulators name from command

```
emulator -list-avds
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Emulator help section make all TCP connections through a specified HTTP/HTTPS proxy](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#startup-options)

The value of  can be one of the following:

```
http://<server>:<port>

http://<username>:
<password>@<server>:<port>
```

The `http://` prefix can be omitted. If the `-http-proxy <proxy>` command is not supplied, the emulator looks up the `http_proxy` environment variable and automatically uses any value matching the `<proxy>` format described above.