# Internet stopped working on Android Emulator (Mac OS)

Tags: android-emulator

I am using Android Studio 2.3(Latest). Till yesterday it was all good and working, today emulator is not connecting to the data network.
I couldn't find any solution working so far. My Mac is running on Mac OS Sierra, connected to WiFi with no proxy.

[image]

Comment: Did you tried restarting it? Also, emulator loose internet connectivity when you switch from one network to another.

Comment: Yes, restarted many times, mac as well as android studio.

Comment: 2021 - Google/Android unable to create an emulator that can connect to the internet

Answer (score 316, accepted):

In Mac OS go to:
System Preferences -> Network -> select Wi-Fi os left panel -> Advanced on right panel -> DNS -> add new DNS server; for example `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` ([Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/)) or `1.1.1.1` and `1.0.0.1` ([Cloudflare and APNIC DNS](https://1.1.1.1/dns/)) or another public DNS provider. Then restart the emulator so the changes take effect.

[image: DNS setup]

Edited jun/2020

Another option is to pass dns-server params when start Android emulator.
According with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/51858653/3328566, I changed the emulator executable name and I created a bash script to load the AVD with param  `-dns-server 8.8.8.8`.

In your Android SDK default folder `/Users/[MY_USER_ACCOUNT]/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator`

1. Rename the binary `emulator` to `emulator_original`
2. Create a bash script named `emulator` that contains:

`#!/bin/bash
    /Users/[MY_USER_ACCOUNT]/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator_original -dns-server 8.8.8.8 $@`

3. Change the script permissions with `chmod +x emulator`

Now, you can start AVD from Android Studio normally

In this case, you don't need to set DNS server in System Preferences. You are setting the DNS server only for the emulator, avoiding other problems

Comment: I just needed one more step after this - restarting the AVD.

Comment: this works for me too. But I'm just scratching my head over why the heck is this happening?

Comment: Works, ... but why?!!

Comment: After this, close the emulator. A reboot isn't enough.

Comment: Please note that 8.8.8.8 is Google's DNS IP, if you're concerned about your own privacy, remove this line once you're done.

Comment: I need to agree with @Skoua. Changing your DNS to Google's public DNS is a huge scratch in your privacy purse. For now this has worked, but we need a better answer to this...

Comment: How is it related to emulator?

Comment: techradar has a list of free dns servers https://www.techradar.com/au/news/best-dns-server

Comment: For the changes to apply you, after you click OK, you need to close System Preferences (at which point it will prompt you to save changes)

Comment: In my case it worked only by adding both 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 to DNS servers

Comment: I don't think this is a solution; it is merely a hack. For many people it is entirely unaccaptable or even impossible to change their local DNS settings. This may work for a developer at home who doesn't care about privacy. I suggest you go with Jez's solution.

Comment: It's because IPV6 is broken in Android. My ISP provides IPV6 DNS, if I disable that it works. Unlike iOS which prepared for this over a decade ago, Google still hasn't fully implemented it.

Comment: wipe the emulator data in android studio > change 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 to DNS servers > restart emulator, it works

Comment: work fine thanks. make sure to wipe data and restart emiulator

Comment: If someone from M1 Chip based laptop, then pls update your android studio, that should solve the issue apart from adding the DNS. 
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7678000, built on August 27, 2021

Comment: I just added an alias to whole command in `.zshrc` file. `alias avd="/path/to/emulator -dns-server 8.8.8.8 -avd AVDNameHere"`. So whenever I want to open emulator i just type `avd` in terminal and it just works.

Answer (score 77):

For me the issue appears to stem from the DNS settings my company enforces.

In order to be able to get network access for my emulator I needed to launch the emulator with the same corporate dns-server specified.

I'm on a Mac, so first I checked my network settings to find what my DNS was set to:

```
System Preferences -> Network -> Wi-Fi -> Advanced -> DNS
```

Then navigated to the sdk emulator location (for convenience):

```
cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator
```

Then listed the available emulators:

```
./emulator -list-avds
```

Then ran the desired emulator with dns server override:

```
./emulator @<emulator_name> -dns-server <dns.server.ip.address>
```

It would be nice if I could set this DNS to be used by emulators launched through Android Studio, but hopefully these steps help someone else in a similar position.

Comment: When I run this command line ./emulator -list-avds, I do not load an emulator

Comment: What are dns settings?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky your DNS settings are likely to be what your company computer is using. If in doubt contact your network administrator.

Comment: @dbenitobaldeon 1) ensure you've downloaded an android emulator through android studio 2) ensure that the path `~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator` does indeed point to a folder containing an `emulator` script - otherwise look up the location of your android studio emulator install directory and use that instead.

The path will obviously be different if you're on a windows machine.

Comment: In case I misunderstood your initial question @IgorGanapolsky `DNS` means "Domain Name Server", the place your computer looks to find out what IP corresponds to a website name. Eg, `google.com` might resolve to the IP address `216.58.198.174`, which is what your computer will actually use to find the website. Your DNS settings specify what server your computer will use for this service.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky open `System Preferences` select `Network` then `Wi-Fi` then `Advanced` then `DNS`, and you should see a pane containing a sequence of numbers, such as `8.8.8.8`. This is a DNS address.

Comment: In newer macOs, may be under `System Settings -> Network -> Wi-Fi -> Details -> DNS.`

Answer (score 46):

i tried purge all android studio files and reinstall, start with -dns-server, wifi dns to 8.8.8.8, none of them not working for me. I found it only can using ip address in emulator but this post saved me.
[Post](https://www.bswen.com/2021/08/others-how-to-enable-android-emulator-internet-access.html).

1. Turn off you macos wifi
2. Cold boot emulator
3. Waiting the emulator's wifi connected (limited connection but it's ok)
4. Turn on you macos wifi

it's working now.

Comment: Simple and effective answer. Thanks, it helped. Still I'm wondering why did it happen.

Comment: works for me too, setting new dns not works, but this is working

Comment: My emulator stopped having internet connection after updating the latest emulator release (31.3.13). Your steps solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Amazing, it's 2023 and this still works, thank you!

Comment: That worked for me as well! I had lost almost 2 hours trying other solutions, so I'm happy I came across yours

Comment: Worked for me June 2023!

Answer (score 32):

I'm new to Android Studio and just ran into this issue. Network in the sim was working fine and stopped working for some reason. Didn't like any of the solutions above, so I poked around the AVD Manager and found an option to wipe the data on the sim.

1. quit the sim
2. open AVD Manager
3. Actions > open down arrow for more options
4. select Wipe Data
5. restart sim

[image: Wipe simulator data in AVD Manager]

Comment: Didn't expect this to work but it did, worth giving it a go before changing system-wide DNS settings.

Comment: This didn't work for me. AndroidWiFi still can't find Internet

Comment: Worked perfectly the first time. Using an Apple Silicon Mac. Glad to see such a simple solution.

Answer (score 16):

Go to open AVD manager and click wipe data

[image: Click on the wipe data]

That's it now the Internet will work. This is how I solved my Issue.

Answer (score 9):

It's a bug with IPv6 name resolution, removing any IPv6 nameserver in `/etc/resolv.confg` fixes the issue, see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155686508#comment3

Comment: This is it kind sir!!
Adding Google's DNS to MacOS's system preferences didn't work.
Wiping AVD data didn't work.
This for me is the solution! Thanks!!

Comment: That's still a problem. IPv6 DNS was present in the macOS configuration,  changed it to Google's default and cold rebooted it to work.

Answer (score 8):

You can go to: System Preferences -> Network -> Wi-Fi -> Advanced -> DNS

So you add a new DNS 8.8.8.8. It might solve your problem.

Comment: After trying all of the ones on this page. This one did the trick. Remember to restart the simulator after setting it.

Answer (score 5):

None of the answers worked for me on a m1 mac, I was not even able to connect to localhost for the react-native development server.

The trick for me was to turn off the cellular data "T-mobile," then it would use AndroidWiFi for internet and everything worked fine.

Here's a screenshot of my working settings:
[image]

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me on an M1 machine

Comment: this isn't working for me... I have m1 mac and I tried turnning off mobile

Answer (score 4):

Couldn't find any solution by tweaking network settings. So added a new virtual device from Tools -> Android ->AVD Manager by downloading a new system image(Android O, API 26). And it's working now.

If you want to use the same API level then make sure to delete the existing system image and download it again.

Answer (score 3):

1. Click Apple menu > System Preferences > Network.
2. Click Advanced.
3. Select the DNS tab.
4. Add 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4
5. Click OK > Apply.
6. Restart AVDs.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Blue Coat Unified Agent, internet wont work. Kindly uninstall it.

**It can be uninstalled by going to below folder-
/Library/Application Support/bcua**

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue but when I followed below step it was resolved.
System preferences-> Network-> Ethernet/WiFi->Advance->DNS->Add->8.8.8.8->
Add->8.8.4.4 and then click on OK and apply the changes and then Cold boot the android emulator from AVD manager/device manager.

Comment: Any idea why this works? What's the significance behind 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find the DNS in the **System Preferences -> Network -> Wi-Fi -> Advanced**, you can just search for **DNS** in the Search bar on Mac
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I simply did a Cold boot for the emulator and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

These step work for me.

1. System preferences-> Network-> Ethernet/WiFi->Advance->DNS->Add->8.8.8.8-> Add->8.8.4.4 and
2. Disable Mobile Data, switch On wifi and use "AndroidWifi"
3. Restart the Android Emulator

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76751926/9774005) method worked for me some time when not worked I followed below:

For me (M1 Mac) I tried all the above methods, but the below one worked for me:
Initially my mac, used Ethernet enabled & WIFI connected.
Now I tried below steps:

1. Turn off Emulator.
2. Turn off wifi in mac.
3. Disable Ethernet service in your system settings.
4. Turn on wifi in mac.
5. Turn on Emulator.

In emualtor, I turned on both mobile data & wifi both turned on.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There was an update available to my Android Studio, i updated it and it worked!

Answer (score -1):

Easiest fix is to plug in a LAN cable in your laptop/computer.
No messing around with the DNS settings needed.

Answer (score -5):

if its an android project, u can change the baseUrl to 10.0.2.2, note this is only applicable from android emulator, will not work on phone

e.g Api endpoint will now look like this:
val baseUri : String = "http://10.0.2.2/restapi/"

val loginEndpoint = "${baseUri}login"

Comment: I wonder in what scenario this might work. Does the url `10.0.2.2` replace `localhost`? In any way, this is not an answer to connect to the internet, but only to your api.