# Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.2 - Android Emulator has no internet connection

Tags: android, android-emulator, macos-high-sierra

Just installed Android Studio 3 on Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.2 and created a virtual device. Lunched the emulator, but it seems that there is no internet connection. Please check the screen grab. What am I missing ?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internet stopped working on Android Emulator (Mac OS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44535500/internet-stopped-working-on-android-emulator-mac-os)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

That occasionally happens to me as well. Just use different DNS and it'll work.

Go to your android-sdk/emulator and run, this will start the emulator:

```
./emulator -avd YOUR_EMULATOR_NAME -dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
```

You can find the emulator name you need by running the command

```
./emulator -list-avds
```

Comment: You are lifesaver! I have changed DNS in MacOS setting and it works from gui now.

Comment: Oh man, Thanks a lot. I 've just had a question: How to do this in UI of emulator?

Comment: I got `** Unknown exception behavior: 0` when setting 2 IP addresses (version `30.0.5`). One did the trick. It had some 10.x IP address for the DNS for some reason.