# Cannot send request with React Native and Axios

Tags: axios, react-native

I've read dozens of answers, and I can't seem to figure this out:

- The request works fine in iOS, but it does *not* work in Android
- I am using React Native 0.57.5 and axios 0.18.0
- I put some logging via

> ```
> axios.interceptors.request.use(request => {
>   console.log('Starting Request', request)
>   return request
> })
>
> axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
>   console.log('Response:', response)
>   return response
> })
> ```

[image]

As it can be seen, the request seems fine. And it is not towards `localhost` but to an actual, running server (I redacted some internal header keys and the full URLs)

- Also put a log statement to `catch` of where I make my axios request:

> ```
> axios.request(config)
>       .then((axiosResponse) => {
>         console.log('GOOD RESPONSE ', axiosResponse)
>
>         // some logic 
>       })
>       .catch((error) => {
>         console.log('axiosResponse ERROR', error)
>         // some other logic
>       })
> ```

And this is what I see in the chrome debugger console:

> ```
> axiosResponse ERROR Error: Network Error
>     at createError (createError.js:16)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:580)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:394)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.js:507
>     at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:190)
>     at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:349)
>     at MessageQueue.js:106
>     at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:297)
>     at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:105)
>     at debuggerWorker.js:72
> ```

This is part of my upgrade from React Native 0.55.0 to 0.57.5, so this axios stuff was working normally before.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you said I think it must be that you didn't ask for internet permissions, if that's the case you need to edit in your android project inside react your manifest file it must be in $your_project_root_directory/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your.package"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
...
</manifest>
```

Other thing that could be is that if you are using http connection. try the following

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">yourinsecureserver.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
                    ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/protecting-users-with-tls-by-default-in.html

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the case. I see `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` right there in my AndroidManifest.xml. And as I said, this started happening as part of my effort to upgrade react native

Comment: Are you able to browse normally from the device?

Comment: Is your url https or http? https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/protecting-users-with-tls-by-default-in.html

Comment: I am an idiot -- I fixed the internet connection and now it works! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44535500/internet-stopped-working-on-android-emulator-mac-os

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you need add the API domain in your react_native_config.xml file like picture bellow:

[Print on Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grXW9.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
   <domain includeSubdomains="false">localhost</domain>
   <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.2.2</domain>
   <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.3.2</domain>
   <domain includeSubdomains="false">192.168.0.9</domain>
 </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```