# How to solve Flutter Error No address associated with hostname in socket_patch lookup()

Tags: android, flutter, http, dio, socketexception

When i try http post request with Dio in my Android emulator, i get the "No address associated with hostname " Exception in this part

Follwing code is already in Manifest

this part

```
      {InternetAddressType type = InternetAddressType.any}) {
    return _IOService._dispatch(_IOService.socketLookup, [host, type._value])
        .then((response) {
      if (isErrorResponse(response)) {
        throw createError(response, "Failed host lookup: '$host'");
      }
```

Manifest

````
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />```
````

Comment: what is the URL you're trying to access? is it localhost perchance?

Comment: it's not a local development server.

The server responses are coming through well with a little bit of waiting..

Comment: If you're on MacOS, check dns settings https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44535500/internet-stopped-working-on-android-emulator-mac-os