# Change Android Emulator microphone's default settings

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, config

When I'm starting my Android Emulator, I click on the three dots at right. Then, in "Extended controls" window, I set the Microphone options all active.

I must do it every time I start it, and it's very annoying. It is possible to make these settings active by default? And how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit**: I was wrong saying there is no other way to allow microphone input. Looked again and found [another commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/5c2a96476a62dbe16d79a0532924f3c10b590e43) later that introduced `allow-host-audio` option. So this is the way to start the emulator with host audio enabled:

```
emulator -avd YourAvdName -qemu -allow-host-audio
adb emu avd hostmicon
```

It seems like it's not enabling the switch in the settings, but that's a pure UI issue, the mic works fine.

**Previous answer:**

I don't believe there is currently a way for this particular setting. Normally emulator setting are saved into `AVD.conf`. [Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/6d16a2cfb5356046e813672b99ef54431eaf1748/android/android-emu/android/skin/qt/qt-settings.h) are all the constants for the persistent settings and microphone settings are not among them. Looking further at the `Virtual microphone uses host audio input` setting I found [the commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/e11e36e2d89059f72bb0eda6979ff57588f939a8) which introduced this setting and as you can see when you toggle this setting it sets `allow_real_audio` in audio subsystem and that's it. No other code is setting this flag. As you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#disable-host-audio) this option is being reset on restart intentionally and hopefully it will be fixed when the described bug is fixed.

Edit: here is a bit more on how exactly the flag is set:
UI switch toggle is handled in [this line](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/e11e36e2d89059f72bb0eda6979ff57588f939a8/android/android-emu/android/skin/qt/extended-pages/microphone-page.cpp#77). It calls [this function](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/e11e36e2d89059f72bb0eda6979ff57588f939a8/android-qemu2-glue/qemu-vm-operations-impl.cpp), which in its turn calls [qemu_allow_real_audio](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/e11e36e2d89059f72bb0eda6979ff57588f939a8/audio/audio.c#1208), which sets `allow_real_audio` flag. This flag is used in the `AUD_read` function

```
    if (!allow_real_audio) {
        // TODO: Also a potential way to pipe fake audio input
        // that is not just all zeroes.
        memset(buf, 0x0, size);
    }
```

Comment: *I found the commit which introduced this setting and as you can see when you toggle this setting it sets allow_real_audio in audio subsystem and that's it.*

Can you indicate me where exactly is this line of code?

Comment: Thanks. Where I can find all of these files in my filesystem? :)

Comment: These files are from aosp project and you can download it if you wish. [Here](https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading) is the instruction how to download aosp. Just specify `emu-master-dev` branch to get the emulator source code.

Comment: @Lore I was wrong saying there is no way to enable the setting. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: This works, and it's ok for me on this project... but with "default" i mean something that I can set on emulator config, then forget about it. Not to activate every time by command line.

Comment: There is seem to be no way to set it as a default. But you can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51858653/2548988) to achieve set-and-forget experience

Comment: The solution is for mac... I am on Windows

Comment: You should be able to do the same on windows with a bat file

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a windows expert. At least you can create a bat file with the exact command from the answer and run it to launch the emulator. Not perfect, but at least no typing every time.